# Cannot start docker on lubuntu - "cannot start container: exec format error"

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I ran `sudo apt-get install docker.io` in my lubuntu 14.10, but it says `cannot start container` when I run this:

```
sudo docker run ubuntu echo "Hello World"

exec format error2015/03/16 16:31:16 Error response from daemon: Cannot start container ad265ac9c2635f42e4244472d181a2121ecba4d855fa33c10599d91aa932d2cd: exec format error
```

Can not find out the answer, guest it maybe related with the lubuntu.

The container is created, but why do I only got the "exec format error"

```
sudo docker ps -a

e92e43115003        ubuntu:14.04        "/bin/echo 'Hello wo   About an hour ago    sharp_hoover   

uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.16.0-31-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 10 17:41:23 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What architecture are you running on? Can you do a uname -a?

Comment: Linux ubuntu 3.16.0-31-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 10 17:41:23 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're running a 32-bit host, which is largely unsupported by Docker. You definitely won't be able to run 64 bit images such as the stock ubuntu.

There are however some 32-bit images you can try, e.g: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/32bit/debian/

You can find some more information here https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7513